# Scrolling with iframe doesn't work with sencha

Tags: extjs

i am trying to embed a html page which has a iframe (with code to dynamically adjust height and width of the iframe according to the content of the SRC) as follows

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="https://www.w3schools.com" width="100%" onload='javascript:(function(ifrm){
var nheight =ifrm.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
var nwidth = document.body.clientWidth50;
ifrm.contentWindow.document.body.style.wordBreak ="break-all";
ifrm.contentWindow.document.body.style.overflow ="auto";
ifrm.width=nwidth+"px";
ifrm.height=nheight+"px";}(this));'></iframe>

  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Page renders properly when trying to scroll, scroll doesn't respond if i try to scroll on the iframe content as i am trying to get dynamic height and width of based on the content and scrolling is set to NO to avoid extra scrolls (due to dynamic height and width).

so is there any way to achieve above.

Getting dynamic width and height and able to scroll

Thanks!!

Comment: Ensure that there are no child elements of the iframe window's body element that have overflow set to hidden. An element as such will prevent the body from identifying overflow and applying scrollbars. Do you have an example of the body in the iframe?

Comment: Its just a simple div tag with repeated data to test the dynamic height and width.Note that below <p> are repeated to test dynamic height and width.There are no child element present with overflow

<div style="font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 10px;">
<p>test doc</p>
<p>we've written this line of code that will get the actual value of '100%' as the plugin will not accept percentages as height:</p>

</div>